# Google reports a sudden increase in 404 errors from crawling pages

Tags: google-index, 404, crawl-errors

My server went down for a couple days.(2-3 august)
15 days later,  Google Webmaster Tools notified me of increase in 404 errors.

The problem is that Google reports 70,000 error pages while it has ever indexed maximum 7000 pages, as shows the index status:

[image]

While this is the crawl error page:

[image]

How can I understand which pages Google cannot find? I can see maximum 1000 errors but these 1000 errors are old and were present before too. And how is that possible that it cannot find 70,000 pages if it had ever indexed maximum 7000?

**Note** I have tried to run Xenu link checker to check for internal broken links and none were found.

**Note2:** In correspondence with the spike in errors (21th august) there were a spike in crawled pages too:

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the 70K+ perhaps consists of all the non-canonical versions of those URLs as well? Since your "server was down", it had no way of knowing the canonical URLs, so it perhaps attempted to crawl... `example.com/page` as well as `example.com/page?foo=1` and `example.com/page?foo=2`, etc.

Comment: that could be, but i doubt i have so many non-canonical urls. Anyway do i have any way to debug this? Since the 1000 errors that G shows are old and doesnt help. How can i know which are the other 69'000 errors?

Comment: If you sort by "Detected" (ascending) do you see any "newer" records? If you "Download" the list, can you download more than the first 1000? Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools) is unfortunately a bit limited when it comes to processing larger reports.

Answer (score 2):

This could happen in the case you have a lot of URL parameters which usually result in a lot of pages being created -Googlebot automatically ensures that not all of these are indexed. However, when your site went down all of these could have shown up as 404 errors.

How does one analyse and clear these?

There is a priority column in the crawl errors report. Sort from 1 to the last and start fixing from 1. Usually we have seen that solving the first 1 has an effect of solving a lot of other errors - In your case 100-1000s of errors will disappear if you solve the first (Since you have 70,000 errors)

We faced a similiar issue recently and this helped. Let us know how that went.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Actually i don't have such pages, and I am thinking now that the server down was not the issue here since the spike in errors happened 20 days after the down

Comment: Google webmasters shows a lot of data with around 3 days lag. Errors appear and disappear witha  much bigger lag. So 20 days seems not far off.